how to resolve localhost not secure problem with vite?
I'm working on a personal project developed with react + tailwind + vite. in my sign-up component, I need to POST some information from the client side ( localhost:5173 ) to the server side ( localhost:5514 ) but I keep getting this error: POST https://localhost:5514/api/auth/signup net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR . I believe it has something to do with the "not secure" warning on the browser, and I can't find any solution for this problem.

I have tried adding some CORS configuration but there's no change.
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import http from "http";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import authRoutes from "./src/routes/authRoutes.js";

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5514;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());


app.use(cors({
  origin: 'https://localhost:5173', 
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
  credentials: true
}));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    return res.send("Hello!");
});

app.options('*', cors());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);

const server = http.createServer(app);

mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL!)
    .then(() => {
        server.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`server is listening on ${PORT}`);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("database connection failed. server didn't start.");
        console.log(err);
    });


There's a separate https package for node servers If you want to handle incoming HTTPS connections. https://nodejs.org/api/https.html

If the browser shows an error, but the page loads, it is probably simply reporting back to you that some connection encryption is working, but not at any serious, modern level.
Most frameworks server's are coming up with SSL turned on, sort of secure-in-name-only.
For example, localhost is listening while using a auto self-signed certificate.
What you want to do here is get detailed information from both the client and the server to see where the SSL handshake is breaking down.
There are a a lot of other ways SSL can fail in the real world, not worth listing all the very rare cases... but as example, the system times might be out of sync.
Possible - only the browser will offer detailed error info, by default.
You could try using http: URL if you are "dogfood" testing, but keep in mind, this is pretty tacky, there's a case for not doing this in the clear.
